# Spring Boot, Spring Security, OAuth2, Google sign in, CORS - unable to establish a connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-api, cors, spring-security-oauth2

I've been at this for four days now and I'm feeling somewhat exhausted from my inability to solve this.

The frontend and backend are separated on different servers, frontend being localhost:3000 running on React, NodeJs, npm (forgive my ignorance here as I'm not sure which of these is actually in charge of the frontend server) and backend running on localhost:8080 on Spring Boot with Spring Security.

Frontend is enabled to connect with Google with a React component which opens up a popup where the user can log in. It then takes the response Google sends and stores the access_token into the Authorization header before initiating a GET request on the backend endpoint '/register'. It gets the info from Google just fine, the problem is on the backend, but first here's the frontend code in case it is relevant:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';
import {googleClientId, animationDurationTime} from '../base/env';
import request from 'superagent';

class Login extends React.Component {
  responseGoogle = response => {
    console.log(response);
    request
      .get('/register')
      //.set('token', `${response.tokenId}`)
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${response.tokenObj.access_token}`)
      .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.body);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        component="div"
        className="login__block-inner"
        transitionName="fade-in"
        transitionAppear
        transitionAppearTimeout={animationDurationTime}
        transitionEnterTimeout={animationDurationTime}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={animationDurationTime}
      >
        <h1 className="text-left">Login</h1>
        <div>
          <Link className="button__link" to="/login/guest">
            Guest login
          </Link>
          <GoogleLogin
            clientId={googleClientId}
            onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
            onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
            className="google__button"
          >
            Employee login
          </GoogleLogin>
        </div>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

The '/register' endpoint it makes a GET call at is as follows:

```
package myapp.web.controller;

import myapp.core.model.User;
import myapp.core.model.enumeration.UserRole;
import myapp.core.service.UserService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@RestController
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  private static final String MYAPP_DOMAIN = "myapp.com";

  @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000/**", allowedHeaders = {"Content-Type", "Authorization"}, methods = {RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.GET})
  @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<Principal> register(Principal principal) {
    OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) principal;
    Authentication authentication = oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication();
    Map<String, String> details = (Map<String, String>) authentication.getDetails();

    String email = details.get("email");
    if (email.endsWith(MYAPP_DOMAIN)) {
      if (userService.findByEmail(email) == null) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setName(details.get("name"));
        user.setRole(UserRole.ADMINISTRATOR);
        userService.save(user);
        log.info("New admin created. Details: {}", details);
      }
    } else {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }


    return new ResponseEntity<>(principal, HttpStatus.OK);
  }

}
```

And my configuration file is:

```
package myapp.web.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import java.util.Arrays;

@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//    @Autowired
//    UserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer customOauth2Template;

  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8080")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type");
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
        .and().csrf()
        .disable()
        .antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/v2/api-docs",
            "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources",
            "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
            "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
  }

    @Bean
    @Order(50)
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
      CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

      configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000/**"));
      configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
      configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
  //    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
      UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
      source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
      return source;
    }

}
```

In the controller I used the @CrossOrigin annotation to configure the REST method, specifying the origin (though I believe by default all origins would be allowed) and the allowed methods (I believe by default only the method listed in @RequestMapping would be allowed but I need to set OPTIONS as well because I run into CORS issues) as well as the allowed headers (primarily for Authorization and I'm not sure why I have Content Type allowed as well).

If I go to localhost:8080/register Spring redirects me to Google to log in and then retrieves the information from the '/register' endpoint just fine, but the problem is when I try to target that endpoint from the frontend. What happens then is that Spring Security kicks in and redirects the request to localhost:8080/login, which I believe is predefined and configured by Spring itself and then I had issues with CORS there as well so I implemented the WebMvcConfigurer which works as a global CORS configurer, thereby removing the CORS issue with the redirect to '/login'.

The problem that remains, however, is that I don't know how to handle contacting Google since I still get errors, seemingly CORS related, when trying to reach it with the '/register' endpoint targeted from the frontend. The problem is that Spring Security seems to want to open up the login page for Google instead of doing anything with the access token I send in the header, and that's probably not strange at all since I don't do anything with it but my main problem is that I don't know how to use it, I don't know how to give it to Spring Security for authentication rather than it doing what it does now.

Here's the current error message as well as the network data:

[Error](http://puu.sh/ztr5t/e52c2d0a93.png)

Network data:

- https://puu.sh/ztraA/2022e82633.png
- http://puu.sh/ztroN/49ff8548ee.png
- http://puu.sh/ztrLt/b0a89b19df.png
- http://puu.sh/ztrJd/8bfb48abe3.png

(The second register and third login are the same as the previous ones, not sure why there is a second call)

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: same problem... did you solve it?